# Proof memcache is faster than file system caching?

Tags: performance, caching, filesystems, memcached, template-engine

Is there any theory that says that a cache should be faster than a file system?

I think that since the file system also uses caching there is no scientific proof that we should move content from file system to a cache such as memcache when the concept of file system is somewhat loose -- like downloading a "file" could be the same as downloading a memcached object.

My concrete example is whether to host a template engine via memcache or file system. Does it matter?

Comment: memcache is optimized for one purpose. A filesystem is optimized for many.

Comment: I tried comparing cache with SQL and the difference in favor of cache was large. But slow database ould be an explaining factor and I don't rule out that a fast file system can be just as fast or faster than memcache. I ask since sometimes I've got the option to either store something in memcache or in file system and a file system could be very fast and I think I could serve a filesystem using memcache

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your filesystem will probably be faster in many situations. E.g. when you need a cache for your "compiled templates", the filesystem will be faster.

And the filesystem caches (especially on linux) will make sure, that your cached templates - which are read often - are available in very short time. The kernel keeps them in an in-memory cache, and reads will be fast as hell.

memcached is a distributed key/value store. It has **different use cases**.

Answer (score 4):

Please read the [memcached about page](http://memcached.org/about) to understand why memcached exists.  Your question doesn't make sense unless you have a magical clustered filesystem cache for your 100 front-end web servers.

Comment: Thank you for the link. "speeding up dynamic web applications by alleviating database load" is not the same as serving static files. So I understand it's very good that I can save a query since I won't have to go to the data layer next time. But to save a file? Serving files from file system seems fast if not faster and if I want to serve just a basic file e.g. CSS or javascript file, isn't file system still a good choice or if I want optimization should I even use memcache if content doesn't change?

Comment: memcached isn't a file cache.  If you're wanting a content server, you should look into varnish or similar.  If you have just one server and the files it's serving all fit within your filesystem cache, you probably don't have a problem and it's not worth it to try to find a solution.